# Gson module not found Blackberry Java application

Tags: java, json, blackberry, gson

I'm developing a simple application for Blackberry and i'm using Google's gson to retrieve some data from a server.

The UI was working fine but when I added the gson part it started failing, it wont run.

When I run the application in the simulator it show this error: "Uncaught: RuntimeException" on that annoying white screen of death and after holding the click button I can see that there is an alert dialog that says "Module 'gson-1.4' not found".

However I did added "gson-1.4.jar" in the Project's Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add External JARs... also, the Gson objects are recognized at my code, no syntax errors at my code.

BTW, I'm using Eclipse and the most recent Blackberry SDK

Please help

Comment: Why is this marked Community Wiki? Anyway: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Eclipse-1-1-can-I-add-external-3-d-party-JAR-library/m-p/490038

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, removing te Wiki tag

Comment: No luck, it's the same problem in that thread but after doing that now my project cant' be packed: com.google.gson.CamelCaseSeparatorNamingPolicy: Error!: Missing stack map in: <init> at label: 24
Packaging project BBSIT failed (took 7.438 seconds)

Comment: I've tried to preverify the class but got this error:
Error preverifying class com.google.gson.annotations.Expose java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/annotation/Annotation

Comment: I am having the same problem but I have successfully preverified the jar that I am using.

Answer (score 3):

Gson is created around Reflection and other stuff that is not present on J2ME, wich the Blackberry API is based on.

So, sadly no Gson for Blackberry.